# Making Banana bread but short on flour: can I use pancake mix?

Tags: baking

I'm making banana bread I am a half a cup short of flour what can I use to substitute? I have pancake mix could I use that to replace the half a cup of flour I do not have?

Comment: How much flour does it call for in total?

Answer (score 3):

Me think you could do it.

A banana bread is more a cake than a bread, and the additional ingredients (mostly sugar) in the pancake mix will not impact that much in the result.

Answer (score 1):

The recipes called for 2 cups of flour. I just  had 1 1/2 cups just used what I had it turned out fine.

Comment: Hello Colleen, your answer is unusual, as pointed out  in Divi's comment, but I think it's OK. You not only clarified how much flour in total (which normally would have been an edit to your question instead of an answer), but you also reported what you did and how well it worked, and this is an answer to our standards. So thank you for coming back to share that info. You can even mark your own answer the accepted one, no problem there.